# What is a proper way to delete a list of objects in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an object User, which has a List of UserDictionary. Each UserDictionary has a List of UserWords with cascade delete.

User.java

```
public class User implements Serializable
{

    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Boolean isVerified;
    private List<UserDictionary> dictionaries = new ArrayList<>();
    private UserTrainingSettings settings;

    //getters and setters there
}
```

And mapping User.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="User" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" table="USER" entity-name="user">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="user_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="login" type="java.lang.String" length="40" not-null="true" unique="true"/>
    <property name="password" type="java.lang.String" length="32" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="email" type="java.lang.String" length="100" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="isVerified" type="java.lang.Boolean" column="verified" not-null="true"/>
    <list name="dictionaries" fetch="join">
        <key column="user_id" not-null="true" on-delete="cascade"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.github.wordsmemoriser.Model.UserDictionary"/>
    </list>
    <one-to-one name="settings" class="com.github.wordsmemoriser.Model.UserTrainingSettings"
                cascade="javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

UserDictionary.java

```
public class UserDictionary
{
    private Long id;
    private User user;
    private String name;
    private List<UserWords> words = new ArrayList<>();
    //getters and setters there
}
```

And mapping UserDictionary.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="UserDictionary" dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true" table="DICTIONARY">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long" column="dict_id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="user" class="com.github.wordsmemoriser.Model.User" fetch="join">
        <column name="user_id" not-null="true"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" length="100"/>
    <list name="words">
        <key column="dict_id" not-null="true" on-delete="cascade"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.github.wordsmemoriser.Model.UserWords"/>
    </list>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

What is a proper way to delete all UserDictionaries from User? Should I iterate this list, delete every UserDictionary from database, then clear this list and update User like this

```
session.beginTransaction();
for(UserDictionary dict : user.getDictionaries())
{
    session.delete(dict);
}
user.getDictionaries().clear();
session.update(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

or should I just clear User's list and then update it like this

```
user.getDictionaries().clear();
session.beginTransaction();
session.update(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: I think that the first solution is appropriate. For further details you can look at the given url : [URL to Stackoverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776098/hibernate-session-delete-an-object-if-exists)

Comment: @anant666 Am I right guessing, that second solution would leave UserDictionaries in DB untouched? Or Hibernate is smart enough to delete them?

Comment: right Hibernate wont delete until you have called session.delete.